# Curved arrows between ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to change the double arrows of the following graphic into 2 curved arrows each beginning and ending at the ellipses. I have illustrated more precise with paint in the graphic below what I mean:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\firstellipse{(0,0) ellipse (2 and 1)}
\def\secondellipse{(5,0) ellipse (2 and 1)}
\def\thirdellipse{(2.5,2.5) ellipse (2 and 1)}
\filldraw[fill=red!20]\firstellipse;
\filldraw[fill=blue!20]\secondellipse;
\filldraw[fill=green!20]\thirdellipse;
\node (A) at (2.5,2.5) {Variation};
\node (B) at (5,0) {Modifikation};
\node (C) at (0,0) {Reflexion};
\draw [thick,densely dotted, latex -latex] (A)->(B);
\draw [thick,densely dotted, latex -latex] (A)->(C);
\draw [thick,densely dotted, latex -latex] (C)->(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use nodes to draw the ellipses, that becomes very easy, because you use e.g. `a.120` as a coordinate, where `a` is the node name, and `120` is an angle.

Here is one possible implementation where the text is added using a `label`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ell/.style 2 args={
    ellipse,
    minimum width=4cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    draw,
    label={[name=#1]center:#2}
  },
  connection/.style={thick,densely dotted, latex-latex}
]
\node [ell={A}{Variation},   fill=green!20] (a) at (2.5,2.5) {};
\node [ell={B}{Modifikation},fill=red!20]   (b) at (5,0) {};
\node [ell={C}{Reflexion},   fill=blue!20]  (c) at (0,0) {};

\draw [connection] (A)->(B);
\draw [connection] (A)->(C);
\draw [connection] (C)->(B);

\draw [-latex] (b.120) to[bend right] (a.330);
\draw [-latex] (a.300) to[bend right] (b.150);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Although, I'd include the fill colour in the definition of `ell` with `ell/.style n args={3}{...,fill=#3!20}` so that you can write `\node [ell={A}{Variation}{green}] (a) at (2.5,2.5) {};` etc.... Or, even better: `ell/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{...}` and then `\node [ell={A,Variation,green}] (a) at (2.5,2.5) {};`

Comment: I forgot to mention that my \node[ellipse] command does not work. It produces the error "I do not know the key '/tikz/ellipse' and I am going to.. "

Comment: @Buh You need `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you mind to explain what (b.120) etc. means, or provide a link where I can read it? (I want the curved arrows also from a<->c, b<->c and it should look symmetric). Thanks so far!

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. (b.120) means I start at node b at 120°, right?

Comment: @Buh Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

well, [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) bit me for my lunch time :-(  anyway, my (very similar) solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
 E/.style = {ellipse, draw, 
             fill=#1,
             minimum width=22mm, inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=3mm},
DL/.style = {thick, densely dotted, Latex-Latex,
             shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1},
DL/.default = 4mm,
BL/.style = {thick, -Latex, bend left}
            ]
\node (A)  [E=green!20]                         {Variation};
\node (B)  [E=green!20, below left =of A.south] {Modifikation};
\node (C)  [E=green!20, below right=of A.south] {Reflexion};
\draw [DL]  (A.center) -- (B.center);
\draw [DL]  (A.center) -- (C.center);
\draw [DL=-4mm]  (B.east) -- (C.west);
%
\draw[BL]   (A) to (C);
\draw[BL]   (C) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes}
\begin{document}
```

[image]